# Combining $lookup aggregation inside updateMany?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of **users** like this

```json
[
 { _id: ObjectId("61a6d586e56ea12d6b63b68e"), fullName: "Mr A" },
 { _id: ObjectId("6231a89b009d3a86c788bf39"), fullName: "Mr B" },
 { _id: ObjectId("6231a89b009d3a86c788bf3a"), fullName: "Mr C" }
]
```

And a collection of **complains** like this

```json
[
 { _id: ObjectId("6231aaba2a038b39d992099b"), type: "fee", postedBy: ObjectId("61a6d586e56ea12d6b63b68e" },
 { _id: ObjectId("6231aaba2a038b39d992099b"), type: "fee", postedBy: ObjectId("6231a89b009d3a86c788bf3c" },
 { _id: ObjectId("6231aaba2a038b39d992099b"), type: "fee", postedBy: ObjectId("6231a89b009d3a86c788bf3b" },
]
```

I want to check if the **postedBy** fields of complains are not existed in **users**, then update by using the **updateMany** query

By the way, I have an optional way to achieve the goal but must use 2 steps:

```js
const complains = await Complain.aggregate()
        .lookup({
            from: "users",
            localField: "postedBy",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "postedBy",
        })
        .match({
            $expr: {
                $eq: [{ $size: "$postedBy" }, 0],
            },
        });
complains.forEach(async (complain) => {
        complain.type = "other";
        await complain.save();
    });
```

Therefore, can I combine 2 steps into a single **updateMany** query? Like $match and $lookup inside **updateMany** query?

Comment: updateMany uses [this command](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/update/#update-statements) lookup stage is not allowed. Maybe look at [$merge](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) or `$out`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MongoDB v4.2+, you can use `$merge` to perform update at last stage of aggregation.

```js
db.complains.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "users",
      localField: "postedBy",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "postedByLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      postedByLookup: []
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "type": "other"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      postedByLookup: false
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "complains",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eWTorzLoMyI) for your reference.

Comment: I have tried it in mongo aggregate and it's worked, thank you!